# Install memwatch on Node v14, Windows 10

Tags: node.js, node-memwatch

I'm trying to install `memwatch` using:
Node `v14.15.0`, npm `6.14.9` and Windows 10, but having no luck.

Has anyone been able to install this recently?

I've followed the [instructions for node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) and installed Visual Studio 2019 with "Visual C++ build tools"

Thanks

Logs:

```
PS C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor> npm install memwatch

> memwatch@0.2.2 install C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Shaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Shaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
  heapdiff.cc
  init.cc
  memwatch.cc
  util.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\src\memwatch.hh(12,9): error C2039: 'Handle': is not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\memwatch.cc) [C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modul
es\memwatch\build\memwatch.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Shaan\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\14.15.0\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): message : see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\memwatch.cc) [C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_module 
s\memwatch\build\memwatch.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\src\memwatch.hh(12,15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' (compiling source file ..\src\memwatch.cc) [C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_m 
odules\memwatch\build\memwatch.vcxproj]

...

C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\src\memwatch.hh(10): message : see declaration of 'memwatch' [C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\build\memwatch.vcxproj]
C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\src\memwatch.cc(249,59): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\build\memwatch.vcxproj]    
C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\src\memwatch.cc(249,59): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch\build\mem 
watch.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Shaan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Shaan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor\node_modules\memwatch
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! memwatch@0.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the memwatch@0.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Shaan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-23T13_14_40_166Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Shaan\dev\monitor>
```

Comment: Nevermind, I found this as the most recent version of memwatch:
https://github.com/airbnb/node-memwatch
It's waiting on a pull-request to fix a current issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use node-memwatch-new@0.0.1

Comment: node 14.15.3
npm 6.14.9
node-gyp 8.4.1
should be ok with node-memwatch-new

Comment: Instead of adding "this should work..." as answers provide detailed answers that will actually provide an answer to the question.

Comment: Can not get what you mean~

Comment: There are still some bug with @airbnb/node-memwatch in windows. So I fork their repo and pub a new npm without bug.